# how to stop mysqldump from recording as slow queries

Tags: query-optimization, mysql, mysqldumpslow

Im recording slow queries longer than 2 seconds. That is running fine except, the daily backups also get recorded in slow log because 1) mysqldump calls select * from xyz (big table); and 2) when inserting the backup into a new db (yesterday's backup, sundays backup, etc).
How to prevent mysqldump from logging slow queries?
Is there a temporary way to switch off slow logging when backup is in progress?
Please suggest.

Thanks,
Vikas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that answers it:

> To control the slow log at runtime,
>   use the global slow_query_log and
>   slow_query_log_file system variables.
>   Set slow_query_log to 0 (or OFF) to
>   disable the log or to 1 (or ON) to
>   enable it. Set slow_query_log_file to
>   specify the name of the log file. If a
>   log file already is open, it is closed
>   and the new file is opened.

Taken from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html